# DB connection refused - credentials exposed

Tags: ee3, codeigniter, database-error, mysqli

So suddenly I get a "Connection refused" to the MySql database on my site which is running ExpressionEngine 3.5.2 in a shared environment. Fine...

...but the stack trace, when expanded, shows the database name, user and PASSWORD!

You can the see the error message here: http://www.huntee.se/db_error.jpg

Now this error screen looks like Codeigniter or EE. Is this really possible??

How do I make sure this doesn't happen again?

Regards,
Matts

Comment: The saving grace is that the stack trace is only shown to logged in super admins.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping for something like that. Thanks Jim!

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment really, but I do not have enough rep to add comments.

Have you tried using '127.0.0.1' as the db host rather than 'localhost'?

Comment: Okay, thanks greebstreebling.

The site is no longer active but I’ll keep your comment in mind for future projects.

What is the difference between the two in regards to how the error message is shown?

Regards,
Matts

Comment: Sometimes the 'mapping' between 127.0.0.1 and 'localhost' isn't available, in MAMP for instance I found that you have to use 127.0.0.1 or the server cannot find the db server to connect to it.